# IPv6 Crash Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, ipv6, uialertcontroller

I have a Swift app using Firebase as backend.

It works perfectly fine on all simulators and my own iOS devices, but when I submitted it to Apple for review, it crashed specifically when the reviewer tapped on a `UIButton` that presents a `UIAlertController` containing my content reporting mechanism:

```
@IBAction func moreActions(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    // 1
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Action", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // 2
    let reportPost = UIAlertAction(title: "Report this post", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.report()
    })

    // 3
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })


    // 4
    optionMenu.addAction(reportPost)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func report() {
    let messageView = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .CardView)
    var config = SwiftMessages.Config()
    config.dimMode = .gray(interactive: true)

    messageView.configureTheme(.info)
    messageView.button?.isHidden = true

    messageView.configureContent(title: "Thank you", body: "We have received your report, and will soon make all necessary actions.")
    SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: messageView)

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("reportedPost").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild(self.passedPurchaseKey) {
            print("this post has been reported before")
            let targetKey = self.passedPurchaseKey
            let value = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: targetKey!).value as! Int
            let newValue = value + 1
            self.ref.child("reportedPost").updateChildValues([targetKey!: newValue])
        }else{
            print("this post has not been reported before")
            let targetKey = self.passedPurchaseKey
            self.ref.child("reportedPost").updateChildValues([targetKey!: 1])
        }
    })
}
```

The reviewer suggested that the crash might due to IPv6 incompatibility. I cannot agree with them since the networking logics above are very similar to the rest of my App, which did not lead to any crashes. Thus I suspect that the crash was due to something else.

Yet I could not be sure because I do not have the required hardwares to test my app under IPv6 environment.

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

//edit 1: crash log added

[crashlog_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBzIo.png)

[crashlog_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koOb1.png)

Comment: You don't have a Mac?! Or your Mac doesn't have a wired Ethernet port?

Comment: I do. I have a macbook pro late 2014, can't connect to ethernet cable without an adaptor.

Comment: Right, but those can be had for USD 20 or less. Go shopping.

Comment: Did you try to build the code on the release mode?

Comment: Whats is * self.passedPurchaseKey*?